# javascript and parseFloat function?

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

```
function myFuntion(stringNumber){
    var number=parseFloat(stringNumber);
}
```

The value of stringNumber is `"38,41"` (the type of this is string) and i want to convert it float. but when i debug the code i see that this converted to the "38" like parseInt. why? can be it derives from server?

Comment: `parseFloat("38.41") === 38.41`. Are you aware that you're not returning anything?

Comment: `typeof parseFloat("38.41");` gives `"number"` and `parseFloat("38.41");` gives `38.41`. You probably have an error elsewhere.

Comment: I could not replicate this in node

Comment: (I see you're fairly new here: **Welcome!**) Next time, please be sure to quote the actual data **correctly**. Saying originally that the `stringNumber` variable contained 38.41 when it really (according to your comment on daneze's answer) contained `"38,41"` wasted several peoples' time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are passing 38,41 instead of 38.41. If so parseFloat will return 38

Comment: yes u r right. the string is like "38,41". how can i solve this? i can't change string because this string is from db.

Comment: @kamal: How can you solve it? Really? Maybe...[String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)?

Comment: you can modify the function like this function stringNumber.replace(/\,/g, ".");